# Turning a mapped network drive into a shared folder

Tags: windows, networking

I'm having an issue dealing with a legacy piece of hardware and how it records data. It only has the functionality to save data points to a shared folder of a local PC. The PC has the shared folder where all the data is currently saved, as well as access to the mapped network drives.

I'm wondering if there is a way to point the shared folder at the network drive, acting as a bridge essentially to allow the hardware to save directly to the network.

Comment: What do you mean the app can save to a shared folder? Can it save to the root of a drive, e.g. `X:`? If so, can you have it save to a mapped drive that way?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can only detect shared folders on the local machine. As in folders actually shared through the windows share wizard. It can't save to the dir root.

Comment: exactly what type of path must the application use? Something like `\\localhost\folder`?

Comment: It basically needs to see a shared folder. The way the hardware is setup is just a drop down of shared folders on the local machine. Anything I can make shared, it can see, but nothing else. The hardware controller is a proprietary install that seems to be setup to only see shared local folders.